# Throwing dice until we throw a $6$ or a second time a $5$. What is the probability that we have finished throwing after exactly $n$ throws?

Tags: probability, dice

We throw the dice until we throw a six or a second time a five (not necessarily in a row), and then we finish throwing. What is the probability that we have finished throwing after exactly n throws?

As @lulu said, there are 2 possibilities:

1. (the n-th roll was the first $6$ and there was no $5$ before) or (the n-th roll was the first $6$ and there was one $5$ before it)
2. the n-th roll was a $5$ and there were no prior $6$′s and exactly one prior $5$

Now I will try to count the possibilities treating each throw as an independent lottery.

$1$'st case (we fix $6$ at n-th place):

- no $5$ before $\implies \frac{1}{6} \cdot \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^{n-1}$ , we choose one of $4$ possibilities in $n-1$ lotteries.
- one $5$ before $\implies \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^2 \cdot (n-1) \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^{n-2}$, we choose one of $n-1$ places for $5$, then we choose one of $4$ possibilities in $n-2$ lotteries.

$2$'nd case (we fix $5$ at n-th place):

- no $6$ before $+$ one $5$ before $\implies \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^2 \cdot (n-1) \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^{n-2}$ , we choose one of $n-1$ places for $5$, then we choose one of $4$ possibilities in $n-2$ lotteries.

Combined probability:

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^{n-1} + \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^2 \cdot (n-1) \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^{n-2} + \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^2 \cdot (n-1) \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^{n-2}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Are these two separate questions?  I assumed we could stop if *either* condition was met.  Assuming that my reading is correct then you need to split into cases:  either the $n^{th}$ roll was the first $6$ and there was at most one $5$ before it, or the $n^{th}$ roll was a $5$ and there were no prior $6's$ and exactly one prior $5$.

Comment: To stress:  your calculation (for the "end in $6$" case) is not correct, since it counts sequences in which multiple $5's$ occur.

Comment: Ohh, I think you are right, I will think about it. I don't know how to calculate the event that there was one $5$ before throwing $6$.

Comment: Place the $5$, the other slots must be from $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: I edited the original post. Is that correct now? @lulu

Comment: Sorry, I read it too quickly.  You have too many factors of $6$.  The logic is good, however.

Comment: Once you have corrected the factors of $6$, you might want to post your solution below.  That way others can check it and the question won't be left hanging.

Comment: You are right. I think I've corrected that - is that ok now? @lulu

Comment: No...now you have too few.  Take the first case, for example....last toss $6$, no $5$ or $6$ prior.  That one has probability $\left(\frac 46\right)^{n-1}\times \frac 16$.  Also you have some problems in the case $n=1$ (but that is easily handled).

Comment: I suggest:  work a couple cases by hand, explicitly.  $n=1$ is a bit misleading,  but $n=2$ or $n=3$ work well.  then you can check your formula against these cases.

Comment: multiply by $1/6$. Can you see why?

Comment: I got no idea why would I multiply anyting by 1/6 @lulu @D S

Comment: I mean, in the first case - last lottery is fixed. I need to think about the other $n-1$ lotteries. Therefore I take $\frac{4}{6}$ to the power of $n-1$. Why would I multiply that by $\frac{1}{6}$? What would make for the representation of that $\frac{1}{6}$ in  the process of choosing the sequences of numbers that I would like to count?

Comment: You need to get a $6$ on the final roll, for that case. That's a probably $\frac 16$ event.

Comment: Yeah, I think I finally got it. Is that correct this time? @lulu

Comment: Yes, this looks good.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much!